# Show error when url isnt allowed list?

Tags: php, regex, list, url

if $text isnt allowed list print error. Dont know how do do it

```
$allowedDomains = array('www.test1.com', 'www.test2.co.uk', 'test3.com');
$text = 'this is my url www.abcd.com/index.php?page=home';
```

Comment: use the in_array function to search in array. first take the url from $text string.

Comment: do you want to test `$text` does contain the `$allowedDomains` values? you are question is not bit clear?

Comment: To bhushya - Yep thats what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$allowedDomains = array('www.test1.com', 'www.test2.co.uk', 'test3.com');

if ( !in_array('your-domain-name', $allowedDomains) {
    echo 'show your error here';
} else {
    echo  'do what ever you want here';
}
```

Comment: what if domain name is inside of text

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing it: create a regex using the list of domains, and then use that to test your text strings.

```
$allowedDomains = array('www.test1.com', 'www.test2.co.uk', 'test3.com');
# concatenate the allowed domains with | and surround with brackets so the regex will
# match any of the array items
# i.e. $regex is (www.test1.com|www.test2.co.uk|test3.com)
$regex = "(" . implode("|", $allowedDomains) . ")";

# a couple of test strings
$texts = array('this is my url www.abcd.com/index.php?page=home',
         'my home page is www.test3.com');

foreach ($texts as $t) {
    if (preg_match("/$regex/", $t)) {
        echo "Found a match! $t\n";
    }
    else {
        echo "No match found: $t\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

> `No match found: this is my url www.abcd.com/index.php?page=home`
>
> `Found a match! my home page is www.test3.com`

Answer (score 0):

I've written a function for you that'll allow you to add / remove domain names and / or domain extensions as you please, taking into account that not everyone types "http(s)" and / or "www" into their domain searches and also the unpredictability of what kind of information might be behind the domain or not:

```
<?php

function testDomain($domain){

    //Set domain names
    $arrDomainNames = array("test1","test2","test3");

    //Set domain extensions like .com .co .info
    //Do NOT add .co.uk! .uk is taken care of in the regex
    $arrDomainExt = array("com","co");

    $cntDomainNames = count($arrDomainNames);
    $cntDomainExt = count($arrDomainExt);
    $i = 0;
    $y = 0;

    $DomNames = "";
    $DomExt = "";

    foreach($arrDomainNames as $value){
        if($i == $cntDomainNames - 1){
            $DomNames .= $value;
        } else {
            $DomNames .= $value ."|";
        }
        $i++;
    }

    unset($value);

    foreach($arrDomainExt as $value){
        if($y == $cntDomainExt - 1){
            $DomExt .= $value;
        } else {
            $DomExt .= $value ."|";
        }
        $y++;
    }

    unset($value);

    $pattern = "/((((http|ftp|https)+(:)+(\/{2})))?+(www\.)?(((". $DomNames .")+\.)+(". $DomExt .")+(\.uk)?(:[0-9]+)?((\/([~0-9a-zA-Z\#\+\%@\.\/_-]+))?(\?[0-9a-zA-Z\+\%@\/&\[\];=_-]+)?)?))\b/imu";
    if(preg_match($pattern, $domain)){
        echo "Domain match!<br />";
    } else {
        echo "Domain not match!<br />";
    }
}

testDomain("www.test1.com"); //match
testDomain("test1.com"); //match
testDomain("http://www.test1.co.uk"); //match
testDomain("test1.com/info.php?who=you"); //match
testDomain("www.google.com"); //no match

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How to make it working with

```
$arrDomainNames = array("test1.com","test2.org","test3.co.uk","test3.net");
```

without

```
$arrDomainExt = array("com","co");
```